# What does the bash command history -r do?

Tags: linux, bash, history

What is the purpose of `history -r`? Given that in the man page:

```
r      Remove a trailing suffix of the form .xxx, leaving the basename.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-history):

> Read the history file and append its contents to the history list.

A custom file can be loaded into your Bash history using the history command. Now when you use `history -r` then it will read the file you name in as your command history.

Answer (score 1):

As Rahul Tripathi says `history -r` is for reading a file into the history.

That bit about `r` and a trailing suffix is from the [`Modifiers`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Modifiers) section of the man page and refers to using `r` after a word-designator in history expansion as in:

```
$ echo foo.bar
foo.bar
$ echo !$:r
foo
```